# Is there a cross-platform signal SIGALRM like threading or asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a method that may take too long to finish. If it took 30 seconds, it should go the next line of code. When using signal, it looks like this:

```
import signal 

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(30) 
result = get_something_that_takes_time() 
signal.alarm(0) 

call_more_methods(result)
```

Now I needed to do it in a cross-platform way. I tried using threads:

```
import threading

def thread_handler():
    raise Exception("Timeout in dateparser search_dates after 30 seconds")

try:
    timer = threading.Timer(30, thread_handler)
    timer.start()
    result = get_something_that_takes_time() 
    timer.cancel()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

call_more_methods(result)
```

But it didn't work. Now I'm thinking to use `asyncio` if possible.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Killing a thread is hard. Can you run this method in a different process?

Comment: @Roy2012 Sadly no, that's why I'm also looking for other options like `asyncio` but I can't find one with the same scenario

Comment: Do you control the code of the long-running function? Can you get it to check some condition every N milliseconds?

Comment: What @Roy2012 said. Also, is the long-running function "stuck" in IO-related code or in CPU-bound code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `asyncio` provided the method that you are waiting on is an awaitable object. The relevant method is called [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for).

```
import asyncio


async def sleep_awhile():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Just woke up...")


async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(sleep_awhile(), 3)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timed out before waking up...")

asyncio.run(main())


# Timed out before waking up...
```